# When 'sales_bestsellers_aggregated_daily' table will get update data?

Tags: magento2, best-seller

In my local **'sales_bestsellers_aggregated_daily'** table is empty, But I need to get the best selling products from this table. I made an order and created shipments also. But this table is empty.

Is anybody knows when this **'sales_bestsellers_aggregated_daily'** will get update with product data?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sales module has a cronjob defined in **magento/module-sales/etc/crontab.xml**:

```
<job name="aggregate_sales_report_bestsellers_data" instance="Magento\Sales\Model\CronJob\AggregateSalesReportBestsellersData" method="execute">
        <schedule>0 0 * * *</schedule>
</job>
```

So you have to configure your Magento's  cron to be running properly and bestsellers tables are going to be populated at `00:00` on your store time.

Answer (score 3):

Admin panel has a section Reports/Refresh Statistics. Select an item(Bestsellers) and press submit.

Answer (score 0):

As @Fel1xx Mentioned, sales_bestsellers_aggregated_daily will get updated at 00:00 every day . 
If you are doing development, and you want to see this table updated immediately when you have placed some orders, you can run manually this cron job 'aggregate_sales_report_bestsellers_data' using [magerun2](https://github.com/netz98/n98-magerun2)

magerun2 sys:cron:run then enter 2 which stays for aggregate_sales_report_bestsellers_data .

It will populate that table for you .